# Why can siblings of a tag in BeautifulSoup4 be strings?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

At first glance, I think it's natural to think that `.next_sibling` and `previous_sibling` should be siblings tags. But it resulted in NavigableString like `"\n"` when I played with it today.

After carefully checking [its documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it has noted that:

```
In real documents, the .next_sibling or .previous_sibling of a tag will usually be a string containing whitespace. Going back to the “three sisters” document:

<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>
You might think that the .next_sibling of the first <a> tag would be the second <a> tag. But actually, it’s a string: the comma and newline that separate the first <a> tag from the second:

link = soup.a
link
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>

link.next_sibling
# u',\n'
The second <a> tag is actually the .next_sibling of the comma:

link.next_sibling.next_sibling
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The `.find_next_sibling` property is for fine-grained searching of an HTML document. Something that CSS selectors cannot do (they can select tags, not strings between tags, for example, you cannot select the string `SELECT THIS` with a CSS selector: `<p>some text</p>SELECT THIS<p>some text</p>`).

If you want to search for a sibling tag, use the `find_next_sibling()` method. You can also emulate `.find_next_sibling` behaviour by passing the `text=True` parameter to `find_next_sibling()`:

```
data = '''
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

link = soup.a
print(link)                                     # <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>
print(type(link.next_sibling))                  # <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
print(link.find_next_sibling())                 # <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>
print(type(link.find_next_sibling(text=True)))  # <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

Comment: Good to know `find_next_sibling()`, I can get the next tag using it. Also it's weird that `find_next_sibling()` doesn't count whitespaces as siblings, as like `.next_sibling`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Documentation page 16 
"""

"""

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: As for this specific example, I was also confused by it by saying that the sibling is a string with a comma and newline, but there is even on comma in the markup, would you help me illustrate it?

Comment: So does it mean that the whitespaces in between tags count? In my opinion, it's not robust to use these siblings properties then.